# issues with python when installing mitmproxy on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, mitmproxy

I am trying to install mitmproxy on a Raspberry Pi, but getting the below issues, which I believe are related to Python. I have tried numerous attempts and searches but no luck at all.

Not sure if this is due to dependencies with libraries need by mitmproxy or else the python installation I have which I built a number of times.

I also attemtpted to use Wifi pumpkin, however this also makes use of mitmproxy which once again due to a dependency on Python I was unable to install. Any other tools were I can MITM traffic coming from a device to the internet? ( I am doing this as part of my dissertation)

```
+ echo Creating dev environment in ./venv...
Creating dev environment in ./venv...
+ python3 -m venv venv
+ . venv/bin/activate
+ deactivate nondestructive
+ [ -n  ]
+ [ -n  ]
+ [ -n  -o -n  ]
+ [ -n  ]
+ unset VIRTUAL_ENV
+ [ ! nondestructive = nondestructive ]
+ VIRTUAL_ENV=/home/pi/Desktop/mitmproxy/venv
+ export VIRTUAL_ENV
+ _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
+ PATH=/home/pi/Desktop/mitmproxy/venv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
+ export PATH
+ [ -n  ]
+ [ -z  ]
+ _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1=#
+ [ x(venv)  != x ]
+ PS1=(venv) #
+ export PS1
+ [ -n  -o -n  ]
+ pip3 install -U pip setuptools
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (18.1)
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/setuptools/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/setuptools/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/setuptools/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/setuptools/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/setuptools/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/setuptools/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (40.6.2)
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
+ pip3 install -r requirements.txt
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Obtaining file:///home/pi/Desktop/mitmproxy (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Collecting blinker<1.5,>=1.4 (from mitmproxy==5.0.0.dev0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/blinker/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/blinker/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/blinker/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/blinker/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/blinker/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/blinker/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/blinker/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement blinker<1.5,>=1.4 (from mitmproxy==5.0.0.dev0->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for blinker<1.5,>=1.4 (from mitmproxy==5.0.0.dev0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

Answer (score 1):

> Any other tools were I can MITM traffic coming from a device to the internet?

Yes, you can use PolarProxy instead of mitmproxy on the Raspberry Pi, as described here:
https://netresec.com/?b=199DC9A

With PolarProxy you'll get PCAP files with decrypted HTTP traffic (including HTTP/2), which can be opened in Wireshark.

Discalmer: PolarProxy is a free tool that is developed and maintained by us at Netresec

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me without venv.

```
apt-get install python-pyasn1 python-flask python-urwid python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libffi-dev
```

and then simple install

```
sudo pip install mitmproxy
```